# Possible bug in angular pristine

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, dynamic-forms

My hope is that I am at fault here and not Angular. I am building a dynamic form using ng-repeat and when I call the form scope it tells me that pristine is true (Even when it's not). It looks like plunker can handle form pristine but not dynamic input pristine. I have more complex code but have boiled it down to the below. The results I am getting when I type in "ASDF" into my first input are:

```
$scope.formName.$pristine = false;<br>
$scope.formName.inputName.$modelValue = "ASDF";<br>
$scope.formName.inputName.$pristine = true;<br>
$scope.formName.inputName.$viewValue = "ASDF";<br>
$scope.formName.inputName.$$rawModelValue = "ASDF";
```

Doesn't make sense as to how the form pristine is true but the input pristine is false.

Here is my basic code:

```
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <form name="formName">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item['-desc']}}
        <input type="text" name="item['-id']">
        <a href="" ng-click="clickMe(item, $index)">+</a>
      </div>

    </form>
    {{isPristine}}
  </body>

</html>

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.formName = {};
  $scope.items = [
    {
      "-id": "1",
      "-name": "FNAME",
      "-desc": "First Name"
    },
    {   
      "-id": "2",
      "-name": "LNAME",
      "-desc": "Last Name"
    },
    {
      "-id": "3",
      "-name": "DOC_DTE",
      "-desc": "DOC DATE"
    },
    {
      "-id": "4",
      "-name": "SSN_TIN",
      "-desc": "SSN OR TIN"
    }
  ];

  $scope.clickMe = function clickMe(item, index) {
    var someItem = item['-id];
    $scope.isPristine = $scope.formName[someItem].$pristine;
  }
});
```

As a final result I need to get the pristine of the dynamically created input so that if something is typed into that field then I can generate another row for the user if they want a second/third first name... If they type nothing then they cannot create another row. I have the row code working already but it doesn't ng-hide the plus sign when the input is not pristine.

Comment: can you provide plunker?

Comment: Hey @Grundy plunker doesn't seem to be able to call the input's pristine only the form's pristine. I tried a few times but got no result. Using the same code from plunker I was able to call the input's pristine in Tomcat.

Comment: what angular version you use?

Comment: @Grundy I am using 1.3.8

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For some reason when I was using a dynamic ng-model and that was stopping my scope.form from recognizing my scope.form.input. Not sure why that happens but I think it's a me bug rather than an Angular Bug.